# opencv has triggered a breakpoint Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap

Tags: opencv, dll, vector, breakpoints

I wrote some code in C++ and OpenCV 2.49 in Visual Studio 2013:

```
cv::Mat mask = Mat::zeros(tmp.size(), CV_8UC1);
```

modify mask that some elements are zeros and some elements are 255's

```
cv::vector<cv::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
cv::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
cv:findContours(mask, contours, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
cv::imshow("Mask", mask);
```

When the method ends, following error appears:

Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 004D0000, 02EBD9D8 )
Project.exe has triggered a breakpoint.

I searched at stackoverflow and other platforms but can't find an answer!

I added the correct opencv path to the "path" environment variable: C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin
and also to the project configurations:
C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib

If I use merge/split from the opencv api it causes the same error, but in this case it is possible to allocate ther vector before going into the method. Then it works. In this case it's not possible to allocate the vector before, because i don't now the size.

I think the problem is that opencv allocates the memory and that's not in the correct heap, but i checked all dll's and paths. Do you have any other ideas?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I replaced the opencv folder with a new downloaded opencv and it works, don't ask me why!

Comment: make sure, you don't mix debug/release dlls.

Comment: they are not mixed... only d for debug (opencv_imgproc249d.lib) do you have another idea

Answer (score 1):

Is the cv::vector declaration valid? You should try std::vector instead of them.
Based on the given code, it is hard to decide what is causing the trouble. Could you provide more details?

Also note that this *"function modifies the image while extracting the contours"*.

You should also check the properties below:

1. Right click on the Project
2. Properties - Configurational Properties - General: set *Plattform Toolset* to *Visual Studio 2013 (v120)*
3. Configurational Properties - C/C++ - Code Generation - set Runtime Library:
   *Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)* for debug builds or *Multi-threaded
   DLL (/MD)* for release build

Comment: thx... all these are correct! I replaced the opencv folder and it worked!